# How replace all "/" to "-" in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like

```
abcd/123/xyz/345
```

I want to replace every "/" with "-" using JavaScript.
 The result string should be `abcd-123-xyz-345`

I have tried,

```
string.replace("/","-")
```

But it replaces the first "/" character only. The result is `abcd-123/xyz/345`

And

```
string.replace("///g","-");
```

is not working as well. 
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex. You need to escape using [backslash `\`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash) before the `/`.

> A backslash that precedes a special character indicates that the next character is not special and should be interpreted literally

```js
var str = 'abcd/123/xyz/345';
let result = str.replace(/\//g,'-');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```js
var str='abcd/123/xyz/345'
var newstr=str.split('/').join('-');
console.log(newstr)
```